# Redux-saga: what mechanism makes it possible for redux-saga middleware to wait and not block everything else

Tags: redux, redux-saga

Redux-saga middleware gives us the feeling as if it runs on a separate thread. When it is told to wait for a certain action to be dispatched by the saga(generator function), it suspends the saga until the action of interest is dispatched. Single js runtime is single threaded, how saga middleware waits for an action to be dispatched and at the same time not block everything else?

Answer (score 2):

Waiting for actions works like this:

1. For any `take()` effect redux-saga middleware makes an entry in *takers* array. An entry contains the pattern and the suspended generator.
2. On any action dispatch the middleware checks the action against the *takers* array. Matching generators are scheduled to be run.

This is asynchronous waiting that doesn't involve blocking anything.

Comment: Is there a link you can provide to support your answer?

Comment: Yes, redux-saga sources: [runSaga.js](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/a5f85f85c761e5ce6152e4c90da358e3d8d2c750/packages/core/src/internal/runSaga.js#L13) reveals that `take()` actually is a take with a "standard channel". Channel logic is in [channel.js](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/2aecdb310db8760ddd2c2513bf1cce7174c289d9/packages/core/src/internal/channel.js). And something interesting in [effectRunnerMap.js](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/a5f85f85c761e5ce6152e4c90da358e3d8d2c750/packages/core/src/internal/effectRunnerMap.js#L80).

Comment: Not as easy as I explain it, but generally everything works through callbacks.